# Does Pycharm 4.5.4 support python3.5?

Tags: pycharm, python-3.5

I am curious if pycharm 4.5.4 has support for python 3.5 yet? If not, is it documented when that will be included? Which release and when will that be released?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

electrometro,

It seems that they have 'initial support' to Python 3.5

Check [this link](http://blog.jetbrains.com/pycharm/2015/05/meet-pycharm-4-5-all-python-tools-in-one-place/) from their blog

This dude [asked them](https://twitter.com/sakal/status/643826068315590659?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw) via twitter about its support, let's keep an eye on their answer

More on their blog about 4.5.x

> Initial support for Python 3.5 with support of PEP 465: a dedicated
>   infix operator for matrix multiplication. We’ll continue implementing
>   support for Python 3.5 with next EAP builds as soon as PEP 484: Type
>   Hints and PEP 448: Additional unpacking generalizations are finalized.

Comment: Yeah, I had seen that. I was hoping someone could elaborate a bit on it. :/

Comment: I updated the answer, I don't think it is an ample support yet.

Answer (score 3):

Today's PyCharm 5 EAP [announces](http://blog.jetbrains.com/pycharm/2015/09/announcing-the-pycharm-5-eap-opening/) support for Python 3.5.

Comment: Looks freaking awesome!